# Execute Powershell Script on Remote SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using a script from: http://www.erichumphrey.com/2011/03/change-sql-startup-parameters-with-powershell/

```
$StartupParameter = "PS >Add-SqlServerStartupParameter '-T3226'"

$hklmRootNode = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"

$props = Get-ItemProperty "$hklmRootNode\Instance Names\SQL"
$instances = $props.psobject.properties | ?{$_.Value -like 'MSSQL*'} | select Value

$instances | %{
    $inst = $_.Value;
    $regKey = "$hklmRootNode\$inst\MSSQLServer\Parameters"
    $props = Get-ItemProperty $regKey
    $params = $props.psobject.properties | ?{$_.Name -like 'SQLArg*'} | select Name, Value
    #$params | ft -AutoSize
    $hasFlag = $false
    foreach ($param in $params) {
        if($param.Value -eq $StartupParameter) {
            $hasFlag = $true
            break;
        }
    }
    if (-not $hasFlag) {
        "Adding $StartupParameter"
        $newRegProp = "SQLArg"+($params.Count)
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name $newRegProp -Value $StartupParameter
    } else {
        "$StartupParameter already set"
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use this powershell script in a loop against several different SQL Servers?  If so, how can I go about doing so?

Comment: You could create a text file with the list of servers. Then let powershell go through that list and run your code. There are plenty of examples if you just search for them.

Comment: Please provide me with an example.  I've searched and found plenty of examples for executing SQL query commands against multiple instances but my Powershell script is not SQL query command (as far as I know).  I've only been working with Powershell for 3 days so I'm a beginner.

Comment: I think you're looking for `Invoke-Command` which can take a script block and run it on a remote server. See here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh849719.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/13/use-powershell-invoke-command-for-remoting.aspx